# Java JADE: Network connection

Tags: java, eclipse, gateway, agents-jade

I'm a beginner on JADE and I need some help with a problem. I have an application which is a Seller and a Buyer buy books. Actually, the seller will add some books and the buyer could search for one to buy it and this is made by using JADE framework.

Now my question is: Is there any possibility to make this application online? For example, if I am a seller on another computer, how could I add some book to be able one buyer see them from other computer? And I can have any number of seller and buyers.

I've heard about `JadeGateway` and `GatewayAgent` and some stuff with webpages...

So if anyone knows how can I do this kind of connection on internet(preferably without some webpages and automatically application) please explain me, or sent me an simple tutorial.

[HERE](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Byq0a6lNd3N3M0JRMjJNWjBBSFk) it's my code, I could not post it here because it's too big. If anyone could give me and idea how to do this based on my code will be perfect, if now... Any kind of advice or tutorial will be great :).

Thanks for you help guys. :D

Comment: Did you ever get any further with this? Currently trying something similar :)